# QListWiget - Flow "BottomToTop"?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I want to know if there is any workaround to the missing flow() property "BottomToTop"?

I'm currently working on a little pet project. Simply a QListWidget, containing a custom made QWidget item, added by the user. No problem with that part. I just want the item to be listed "BottomToTop". Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that just the same as `TopToBottom` but with the [sorting order](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#sortItems) reversed?  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: No, that's not what im looking for. The list starts out empty and the user adds items to the list. But instead of addidng the item to the top, I want it to be added to the bottom. No sorting is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do just need to *insert* the new elements at the bottom instead of the top of your list?
I assume what you call bottom in the beginning for your list?

If so, you can use [QListWidget::insertItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#insertItem)

```
yourListWidget->(0, yourNewWidgetItem);
```

Comment: Well no. Maybe my formulation is abit clumpsy. I'm Actually looking for a "BottomToTop" property for the QWidgetList->flow(). So even when the list is empty. I want it to make the start insertion from the bottom.

Comment: There is no such property ` QListWidget::flow`, what are you talking about exactly? You want to display the list elements from bottom to top? Depending on the style you need, you could just push the list with a spacer.

Comment: The flow() and setFlow() is accessible, it's inherited from QListView. Is it possible to make a perfect fit to the bottom with a spacer, even if the window size change (and therefore also the QlistWidget in my app) ?

Comment: Oh my bad, I did not look at inherited properties! I believe this `flow` stands for *orientation* actually, horizontal or vertical. But the widget is made to grow in one direction only AFAIK. [Spacers/addStretch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) are used to *push* widgets in a layout, so they adapt to size change from both the container (window, layout, parent-widget) and the other widgets in the same layout (i.e. your list view).

Answer (score 0):

This is my closest solution to what I've been asking (Credit to -ymoreau for the Spacer idea).
But I'm not completely happy with it. When enough items are added and the scrollbar appears, an annoying (to my eye) white-space appears at the bottom. Any solution to that? And ofc. is there a more elegant solution to this? Seems abit overkill to me...

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget,
                             QListWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
                             QPushButton, QSpacerItem, QLabel, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtCore

import sys


class SpacerWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SpacerWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.spacer = QSpacerItem(self.width(), self.height(),
                                  QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                  QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.setStyleSheet("border: none;")
        
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.layout.addItem(self.spacer)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class SpacerWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SpacerWidgetItem, self).__init__(parent)

    def setSize(self, width, new_height):

        if new_height < 10:
            self.setSizeHint(QSize(0, 0))
        else:
            self.setSizeHint(QSize(width, new_height))
        

class ItemWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ItemWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.left_label = QLabel("Some info!")
        self.left_label.setMaximumHeight(35)
        self.left_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.right_label = QLabel("Some other info!")
        self.right_label.setMaximumHeight(35)
        self.right_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.left_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.right_label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        
        self.resize(300, 320)

        self.itemsinlist = 0

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.add_btn = QPushButton("Add Item")
        self.add_btn.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 50))
        self.add_btn.clicked.connect(self.addListItem)
        
        self.list_w = QListWidget()
        self.list_w.setMinimumSize(300, 270)
        self.list_w.resize(300, 270)
        self.list_w.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.list_w.setResizeMode(1)

        self.spacer = SpacerWidgetItem(self.list_w)
        self.spacer.setSizeHint(QSize(self.list_w.minimumWidth(),
                                      self.list_w.minimumHeight()))

        self.spacer_widget = SpacerWidget()
        
        self.list_w.addItem(self.spacer)
        self.list_w.setItemWidget(self.spacer, self.spacer_widget)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.list_w)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.add_btn)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.show()

    def addListItem(self):

        new_label = QListWidgetItem(self.list_w)
        new_label.setSizeHint(QSize(self.list_w.minimumWidth(), 35))

        new_label_widget = ItemWidget()

        self.list_w.addItem(new_label)
        self.list_w.setItemWidget(new_label, new_label_widget)
        self.list_w.scrollToBottom()
        self.itemsinlist += 1
        self.spacer.setSize(self.width(),
                            self.list_w.height() -
                            (self.itemsinlist * 35)-2)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.spacer.setSizeHint(QSize(self.width(),
                                      self.list_w.height() -
                                      (self.itemsinlist * 35)-2))
        self.list_w.scrollToBottom()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```